# area of trapezium

Tags: geometry

A trapezium has perpendicular diagonals and altitude 4. If one of the diagonals has length 5, find the area of the trapezium

A 12

B 50/3

C 25/2

D 40/5

I guess the answer is C. I divided the trapezium into two triangles and then it is 5(x+y)/2, in which x+y=length of the diagonal, which is 5, so it's 5(5)/2.

But what if it is a irregular trapezium? The diagonals will not be the same.

I didn't use the altitude so I think my answer is wrong.
What should be the answer?

Comment: First, we need to know the nationality of this shape.  Is it a British trapezium (US trapezoid), or a US trapezium (irregular quadrilateral).

Comment: It is not given...

Comment: Where are you located then, @zzz?

Comment: Ok... so a trapzium has a pair of parallel sides then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Trapezium]

$AH=4$, $AC=5$ $\rightarrow$ $HC=3$.

$\displaystyle \frac{AB}{AO}=\frac{DC}{OC}=\frac{AC}{HC}=\frac{5}{3}$.

$\displaystyle AB+DC=(AO+OC)\cdot \frac{5}{3} = \frac{25}{3}$.

$\displaystyle S_{ABCD}=AH\cdot \frac{AB+DC}{2}=4\cdot \frac{25}{6} = \frac{50}{3}$.

Comment: AB+DC=(AO+OC)⋅5/3 ??? How come?

Comment: i understand now...